# Can I cancel a queued batch?

Tags: fiz

I queued up a batch, but after finishing the pervious one, one of my employees levelled up. I chose to improve her craft stat, and I don't want it to go to waste.

Can I cancel that batch and make a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just cancel a queued batch. You can, however, do one of the following:

- Any time before the batch begins to brew, you can queue up a different batch and replace the originally queued batch.
- When you have nothing brewing but something is queued (such as when your holding area is full), you can fire an employee to cancel the batch.

With either workaround, any ingredients purchased but unused will remain in your inventory.