# How to brew multiple batches at once

Tags: fiz

I saw at the start of the game about brewing multiple batches, but quickly dismissed the dialog without reading it all. So how do you go about brewing two batches at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog at the start of the game doesn't actually say that you can brew multiple batches at once (and in fact **you cannot brew more than one batch at once**). Rather, it talks about how you can queue batches.

When a batch is queued, the ingredients are immediately deducted from your supplies, but the batch itself doesn't start until your current batch is cleared (i.e. placed into storage or immediately sold). As soon as that happens, the batch will begin, meaning that there is no wasted time between batches. If you somehow cancel a queued batch (see [Can I cancel a queued batch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149469/can-i-cancel-a-queued-batch)), the ingredients are returned.